# Need to separate information

Tags: t-sql, csv

I have a ClientID formatted as a link to the file, it looks like:

```
Doe, John (W21135446).
```

I need to separate out this to be:

```
Last Name  First Name   File Number
Doe        John         W2135446
```

Including removing the `()` around the file number. How do I write the T-SQL code to do this for me?

Comment: pls post your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the `CHARINDEX()` and some string-manipulating system functions.

```
SELECT val.ClientID,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(ClientID, CHARINDEX(',', ClientID)-1))) AS LastName,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ClientID, CHARINDEX(',', ClientID) + 2, CHARINDEX('(', val.ClientID) - (CHARINDEX(',', ClientID)+2)))) AS FirstName,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ClientID, CHARINDEX('(', ClientID)+1, (CHARINDEX(')', val.ClientID) - CHARINDEX('(', ClientID)-1)))) AS FileNumber
  FROM (VALUES ('Doe, John (W21135446)')) AS val (ClientID);
```

There are some notable caveats that always accompany working with strings like this: any name value with a comma (something like "Jones, Jr") will break, same with unexpected positions of the characters "(" and ")". So long as all of your data matches this exact pattern, this should help you get the job done.

I used the `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` functions to remove any leading or trailing spaces because I don't entirely trust my string-math, but they're not required so long as you verify your starting and ending points. Also, pay close attention to the arithmetic groupings and order of operations.

Output:

| ClientID | LastName | FirstName | FileNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe, John (W21135446) | Doe | John | W21135446 |

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this depending on what version of SQL Server you are on. Each of these:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'Doe, John (W21135446).'

--==== 1. CHARINDEX + APPLY
SELECT
  ClientId  = @string,
  LastName  = SUBSTRING(@string, i1.Pos+1, i2.Pos-i1.Pos-1),
  FirstName = SUBSTRING(@string, 0, i1.Pos),
  FileNumer = SUBSTRING(@string, i2.Pos+1, i1.ln-i2.Pos-2)
FROM        (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',@string),LEN(@string))) AS i1(Pos,Ln)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('(',@string,i1.Pos)))       AS i2(Pos);

--==== 2. DELIMITEDSPLIT8K + CROSS TAB APPLY
SELECT 
  ClientId   = @string,
  LastName   = MAX(CASE s.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN TRIM(',() .' FROM s.item) END),
  FirstName  = MAX(CASE s.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN TRIM(',() .' FROM s.item) END),
  FileNumber = MAX(CASE s.ItemNumber WHEN 3 THEN TRIM(',() .' FROM s.item) END)
FROM     dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string,' ') AS s;
```

**Both Return:**

```
ClientId                LastName    FirstName  FileNumer
----------------------- ----------- ---------- -----------
Doe, John (W21135446).   John       Doe        W21135446
```

**Against a table:**

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @strings TABLE (ClientID VARCHAR(100));
INSERT  @strings VALUES('Doe, John (W21135446).'),('Smith, Fred (X21139999).'),
                   ('White, Walter (BCH20XD0).'),('Black, Jack (998877).')

--==== 1. CHARINDEX + APPLY
SELECT itvf_extract.*
FROM   @strings AS s
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    ClientId   = s.ClientID,
    LastName   = TRIM(SUBSTRING(s.ClientID, i1.Pos+1, i2.Pos-i1.Pos-1)),
    FirstName  = TRIM(SUBSTRING(s.ClientID, 0, i1.Pos)),
    FileNumber = SUBSTRING(s.ClientID, i2.Pos+1, i1.ln-i2.Pos-2)
  FROM        (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',s.ClientID), LEN(s.ClientID))) AS i1(Pos,Ln)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('(',s.ClientID, i1.Pos)))          AS i2(Pos)
) AS itvf_extract;

--==== 2. DELIMITEDSPLIT8K + CROSS TAB APPLY
SELECT 
  ClientId   = s.ClientID,
  LastName   = MAX(CASE sp.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN TRIM(',() .' FROM sp.item) END),
  FirstName  = MAX(CASE sp.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN TRIM(',() .' FROM sp.item) END),
  FileNumber = MAX(CASE sp.ItemNumber WHEN 3 THEN TRIM(',() .' FROM sp.item) END)
FROM        @strings                             AS s
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.ClientID,' ') AS sp
GROUP BY    s.ClientID;
```

**Both Return:**

```
ClientId                   LastName  FirstName  FileNumber
-------------------------- --------- ---------- -----------
Doe, John (W21135446).     John      Doe        W21135446
Smith, Fred (X21139999).   Fred      Smith      X21139999
White, Walter (BCH20XD0).  Walter    White      BCH20XD0
Black, Jack (998877).      Jack      Black      998877
```

Answer (score 0):

have a play.....reasonably flexible for up to a 4 part split

```
CREATE TABLE #yourtable(
   reference VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO #yourtable(reference) VALUES 
('Doe, John (W21135446)'),
('(Doe), John [W21135446]'),
('Jones [Bill] (W2)'),
('{Smith}, Fred, 684664')
;

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT reference,
    REPLACE(
    TRIM(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(reference,'()|[]{},',REPLICATE('*',8)),'*','')) ,' ','.' )AS extracted
FROM #yourtable
)

SELECT 
reference,
PARSENAME(extracted,3)  as Lastname,
PARSENAME(extracted,2)  as Firstname,
PARSENAME(extracted,1)  as FileNo
FROM CTE

drop table #yourtable
```